# Best way to configure 2 routers with 1 modem?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, ethernet

I have read some posts about this issue, but they all seem to differ slightly from mine,

Our house has 1 wireless router set up with all 5 Ethernet ports full. The router is connected via Ethernet cable on its WAN port to our cable modem, which is connected via coaxial to our cable company.

Now, I also happen to have a spare router in my room, as well as a coaxial port. I kind of have my own mini-setup, and I only connect to the wireless router via WiFi for Internet purposes (I can't use ethernet because of the distance between router and PC.) I am also setting up a web server and ftp server, and need to forward ports 21 and 80. The problem is I am not the owner of the wireless router downstairs. I can only connect to it for Internet purposes: I know the encryption key, but not the login to the router console, and it's not the default.

Is there any way that I can maybe plug my spare router into another cable modem and into the wall and just use that (completely avoiding the initial router) or to somehow run both routers off of one cable modem (without hooking them up.) I want them to be completely separate, so port forwarding works and they don't mingle with each other.

I've also read most IPs only allow one IP per household, so I don't know if the coax port in my room works.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Desperate PC Networking guy

Comment: You might look into usung UPnP to open ports on the router you're not able to administer directly.

Answer (score 0):

Most ISP's only allow one modem at a time. For me, if I get a new modem and plug it into the same port as the old one, I still have to contact the ISP to register the modem. Also, the coaxial probably isn't connected in the first place. Most ISP's charge fees for an another external IP address. Be careful as some ISP's start charging for the additional IP address required for the new modem without asking you.